# tf.keras convolutional architecture isn't working

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, autoencoder

The following problem is a reduction of a real problem I had, while I have been designing an elementary autoencoder arch.
The following example is enough to reproduce exactly the error I had.
I have been trying around two days now, but I can't find any way out of it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import random
import os

RES = [256, 256]
def generator_data(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(6):
            yield tf.zeros((1, 256, 256, 3)), tf.zeros((1, 256, 256, 3))

def mymodel():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    # 256 x 256 x 8
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
    # 128 x 128 x 8
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    # 128 x 128 x 16
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
    # 64 x 64 x 16
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    # 64 x 64 x 32
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
    # 32 x 32 x 32

    # 32 x 32 x 32
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    # 32 x 32 x 32
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
    # 64 x 64 x 32
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    # 64 x 64 x 16
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
    # 128 x 128 x 16
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    # 128 x 128 x 8
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
    # 256 x 256 x 8
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same'))
    return model


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # import some data to play with
    x_val, y_val = zip(*generator_data(20))

    model = mymodel()
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())
    model(tf.zeros((1, 256, 256, 3)))
    model.summary()

    # generator_data(train_list)
    model.fit(x=generator_data(1000),
        validation_data=(list(x_val), list(y_val)),
        verbose=1, epochs=1000)
```

Firstly I have the strange behavior of a model.summary() that contains:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              multiple                  224
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) multiple                  0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            multiple                  1168
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 multiple                  0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            multiple                  4640
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 multiple                  0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            multiple                  9248
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d (UpSampling2D) multiple                  0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            multiple                  4624
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2 multiple                  0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            multiple                  1160
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2 multiple                  0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            multiple                  73
=================================================================
Total params: 21,137
Trainable params: 21,137
Non-trainable params: 0
```

only multiple on output shape.
 I have looked it up [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25036#issuecomment-589382569) but the workaround doesn't seem to work.
 But secondly and more importantly I get the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), for inputs ['input_1'] but instead got the following list of 120 arrays: [<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 256, 256, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.],
         ...,
         [0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.],
         [0....
```

which for my unserstanding makes no sense at all. My generator returns `[batch, x-dim, y-dim, channel]` (I have tried also with `[batch, channel, x-dim, y-dim]` but also no luck). And in this case the batch equals 1 and not 120.
As I said I cannot tackle/debug these problems no matter what, so I would really appreciate your help.
I am quite new to DL but not in python and I am using Tensorflow-2.1.0, in python-3.7

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve those problems by updating to tf-2.2 nightly and using the tf.data module.

In case you have the same problem, have a look here:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import random
import os
from functools import partial

RES = [256, 256]
def generator_data(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(6):
            yield tf.zeros((1, 256, 256, 3)), tf.zeros((1, 256, 256, 3))

def generator_data_val(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(6):
            yield tf.zeros((256, 256, 3)), tf.zeros((256, 256, 3))


def model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(256, 256, 3)))
    # 256 x 256 x 8
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
    # 128 x 128 x 8
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    # 128 x 128 x 16
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
    # 64 x 64 x 16
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    # 64 x 64 x 32
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
    # 32 x 32 x 32

    # 32 x 32 x 32
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    # 32 x 32 x 32
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
    # 64 x 64 x 32
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    # 64 x 64 x 16
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
    # 128 x 128 x 16
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    # 128 x 128 x 8
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
    # 256 x 256 x 8
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same'))
    return model


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # import some data to play with
    x_val, y_val = zip(*generator_data_val(5))
    x_val, y_val = list(x_val), list(y_val)


    model = model()
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())
    model(tf.zeros((1, 256, 256, 3)))
    model.summary()
    train_dataset = generator_data(5)

    gen = partial(generator_data, n=5)
    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        gen, output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32),
        output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([1, 256, 256, 3]), tf.TensorShape([1, 256, 256, 3]))).repeat()
    val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val, y_val)).batch(2)

    # generator_data(train_list)
    model.fit(x=train_dataset,
        steps_per_epoch=40,
        validation_data=val_dataset,
        verbose=1, epochs=1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the working code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import random
import os
import numpy as np

RES = [256, 256]
def generator_data(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(1):
            yield tf.zeros((1, 256, 256, 3)), tf.zeros((1, 256, 256, 3))

def mymodel():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    # 256 x 256 x 8
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
    # 128 x 128 x 8
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    # 128 x 128 x 16
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
    # 64 x 64 x 16
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    # 64 x 64 x 32
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
    # 32 x 32 x 32

    # 32 x 32 x 32
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    # 32 x 32 x 32
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
    # 64 x 64 x 32
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    # 64 x 64 x 16
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
    # 128 x 128 x 16
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    # 128 x 128 x 8
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
    # 256 x 256 x 8
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same'))
    return model


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # import some data to play with
    z = list(zip(*generator_data(2)))

    x_val = z[0][0]
    y_val = z[0][1]

    model = mymodel()
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())
    model(tf.zeros((1, 256, 256, 3)))
    model.summary()


    print(x_val.numpy().shape)
    print(y_val.numpy().shape)
    model.fit(x=generator_data(10),
        validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
        verbose=1, epochs=1)
```

You were using unzip with the generator in the wrong way. I type-casted the output to a list so that it's subscribable. One of the useful trick is to print the shapes and len of the X, y in each step to find out where the bug is.

Update:

Yes, exactly but you need to pass a tensor of shape [batch, 256, 256, 3]. But if a is a list, and a[0] has shape [1, 256, 256, 3], then you need to pass a[0] to the model and that's what I did. But, you were passing a. But a is a list, not a numpy array/tensor and even if we typecast it to a numpy array we'll get shape = (1, 1, 256, 256, 3) - which is not valid.

Also, in your generator_data why you're using an unnecessary second loop?

```
def generator_data(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(1): # ??????? Why?
            yield tf.zeros((1, 256, 256, 3)), tf.zeros((1, 256, 256, 3))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you provide a working example that does what I intended to do? For me this is only a proof that the problem was on validation data, for which thanks.  Did you read it from the code or from experience? More than that I don't understand why output shape is multiple and how I should provide my data for validation. Right now you provide only single tensors, which is not what I would like to do.

Comment: If I run:
`x_val, y_val = zip(*generator_data(20))`
`a = list(x_val)`
`b = list(y_val)`

I get a list of tensors (which in my point of view should be tottaly -fine).
Basically this equivalent with what you do, but you just provide a single tensor for validation and not a list (or a collection of them), which is the intended.

`(Pdb) print(type(a))`
`<class 'list'>`
`(Pdb) print(type(a[0]))`
`<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>`
`(Pdb) print(a[0].shape)`
`(1, 256, 256, 3)`
`(Pdb)`

Comment: I don't use an unnecessary second loop. In my initial code I have range(6). I tried to replicate how my data look like as this is an example intended for testing.

Comment: Anyway I found a solution, but pradoxically it had to do first with the version of tensorflow. I fixed the whole problem first by updating to nightly 2.2 and then by using the tf.data module.